# Azure DevOps Custom Task Extension: powershell.exe / node.exe exit code: 5

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have PowerShell Script as a custom task inside a Build pipeline. The steps of these tasks are:

1. Checkout a repositroy branch
2. Compile a solution in these branch
3. Copy the checkout and the compiling results to a server inside the network

(because of some legacy stuff I can't compile the solution on the server directly)

To make these task more handsome, I wrap this PowerShell Script inside a custom build task.

The `index.ts` looks like:

```
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');

async function run() {
    try {
        //PARAMETERS
        var params: string[] = ['Major', 'Minor', 'Work', 'Share', 'RepositoryUri', 'Branch', 'ProjectConfig', 'Include', 'Exclude'];
        var required: boolean[] = [true, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, false];
        var paramList: string[] = [];

        //LOOP ALL PARAMETERS
        for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var item: string = tl.getInput(params[i], required[i]) || '';
            if (item != null && item != '') paramList.push('-' + params[i] + ' ' + item.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ','));
        }

        //START CHILD PROCESS
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, child;
        console.log('##[command][js] call: powershell.exe ' + __dirname + '/DeployGit.ps1 ' + paramList.join(' '))
        child = spawn('powershell.exe', [__dirname + '/DeployGit.ps1 ' + paramList.join(' ')]);

        //REDIRECT CONSOLE OUTPUT
        child.stdout.on('data', function (data: string) { console.log(data.toString()); });
        child.stderr.on('data', function (data: string) { console.log(data.toString()); });
        child.on('exit', function (code: number) { console.log('##[command][js] powershell exit code:', code); process.exit(code) });
        child.stdin.end(); //END INPUT
    }
    catch (err) { tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message); process.exit(-1) }
}

run();
```

So the only job of this custom task is to call the PowerShell script.

---

#### The Problem

If I execute the PowerShell script with a PowerShell Buildpipeline Task, everything is fine. The Task takes about **20 min**, but every thing works.

If I execute the wrapped custom task the task throw an error after **~11-12 min** in the **3. phase** of the task (*Copy the checkout and the compiling results to a server inside the network*)

[image]

---

#### The Error Message

```
[ps1] copy items from 'D:\AzureDevOpsData\DeployGit\Folder' to '\\my-server\DeployGit' # <- LAST EXECUTET COMMAND [Copy-Item $Work -Destination $Share -Recurse -Force]

##[command][js] powershell exit code: 5
##[error]Der Exitcode 5 wurde vom Prozess zurückgegeben: Dateiname "D:\AzureDevOpsData\AgentA\externals\node\bin\node.exe", Argumente ""D:\AzureDevOpsData\AgentA\_work\_tasks\DeployGit_ff191cd0-69d5-402d-aa18-9566fb6c511c\1.0.6\index.js"".
##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException: Der Exitcode 5 wurde vom Prozess zurückgegeben: Dateiname "D:\AzureDevOpsData\AgentA\externals\node\bin\node.exe", Argumente ""D:\AzureDevOpsData\AgentA\_work\_tasks\DeployGit_ff191cd0-69d5-402d-aa18-9566fb6c511c\1.0.6\index.js"".
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, IList`1 contentsToStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, IList`1 contentsToStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
##[section]Abschließen: Task: DeployGit.ps1
```

My interpretation of the error message is that **node.exe** thorws an error with the exit code 5.

In this [article](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-system-error-codes-exit-codes-description) windows use error code 5 for `Access is denied`. But it more feeling like **node.exe** can't handle the long copy process for any reason.

---

#### Conclusion

I used the custom wrapped tasks in many cases and it is the first time that I have a problem, maybe it is relatet to the long execution time?

I'am sorry for the long and the very specific problem, I only hoped that some other developer run into a similar situation, cause I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Why do use typescript in the custom task? you can use powershell, maybe in native powershell task the error will not will be..

Comment: Cause I learn it from microsoft how to create custom tasks [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops). The main goal was that I need a supported paramater input (like VsTest Task). Where you get structuted parameter input boxes with help messages. I don't know exeactly how I could achive this only with powershell (but i would prefer it), do you have an example @ShaykiAbramczyk?

Comment: Check my this repo: https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk thank you for your share! I realy like that approach to call the PowerShell script directly. I don't recognize this opportunity after reading [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops). I use your template to rebuild my stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea, I think is not found in the docs... but you can also find few tutorials about it, if it will solve the error please update me :)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have on last unsolved problem: before, I was able to pass enviroment variables (`$env:`) as argument to the PowerShell script like `$env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI$env:BUILD_PROJECTNAME/_git/$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME` for the *clone repository url*. If I pass it now with your appraoch, the script receive `$env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI$env:BUILD_PROJECTNAME/_git/$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME` and not `https://my-server/Collection/Project/_git/Project`. Do you know how I could pass environment variables to the PowerShell Tasks?

Comment: How do you pass the args, can you show an example?

Comment: In **DeployGit.ps1**: `param([string]$RepositoryUri)` and below that `$RepositoryUri = Get-VstsInput -Name 'RepositoryUri'`. And in the task extension I enter `$env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI$env:BUILD_PROJECTNAME/_git/$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME` in the input textbox for the *RepositoryUri*

Comment: Damn I get it. The issue is because of the single quotes in `$RepositoryUri = Get-VstsInput -Name 'RepositoryUri'` or?

Comment: In the input text out `$(system.task....)` not `$env:....`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It works like charm. You template is a inspiration. Thanks a lot for sharing! I have one last question: do you know who to achive the `advanced options` pane like in the `Copy Files` task, where you can set up the checkbox `clean target`?

Comment: You need to add a group, add there inputs (like clean target) and handle the inputs in the ps script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instaed of wrap the PowerShell script with TypeScript you can use the PS script directly in your custom build task.

In the `task.json` you need to configure it in this way:

```
"execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
        "target": "your-script.ps1",
         "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
    }
 }
```

You can check in [this](https://github.com/shayki5/azure-devops-create-pr-task) repo how to handle the inputs in the PowerShell script.